# how to read web.config in another Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

In My project I have some Layer :

- Domain Layer
- DataLayer
- MvcApp
- ServiceLayer

MvcApp hase **DomainClass**,**DataLayer** and **ServiceLayer** Refrences.

In **DataLayer**  I need Read some **AppSetting** Key in MvcApp's web.Config
. 
I cant Add MvcApp reference to DataLayer because its Circular .
which way I better :

**way 1:**

For do this , I created I Webservice in MvcApp and user that in DataLayer for read **AppSetting Key** .

**way 2:**

I create a new Layer (middle Layer) and Add MvcApp Reference to it And use middle Reference in Daya Layer .
Which way is better ?

Now , I want Know which one is a  Good way ?

I need your Idea to do this .
Thanks ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, your entire stack lives in the same server. That is, creating a web service to exchange configuration settings isn't a good idea.

You don't need a reference to the MVC project to read application configuration settings: you just need to use `ConfigurationManager` class wherever you want to get something, since .NET configuration model is transversal: `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someKey"]`.

Don't forget to add a reference to `System.Configuration` framework assembly.